# Why does lifecycleScope.launch in a fragment block the UI thread?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, kotlin-coroutines

This is blocking the UI thread, but if I use GlobalScope then the UI would't be blocked.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {

            activity?.runOnUiThread {
                Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.txt_savinginprogress), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            val fileName = "Picture" + System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
            val folderName = "BucketList"

            val bitmap: Bitmap? = photoURI?.let { it1 -> getBitmapFromUri(it1) }

            activity?.let {
                bitmap?.let { it1 ->
                    PhotoSaveHelper(it).savePhoto(fileName, folderName, it1)
                }
            }

            activity?.runOnUiThread {
                Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.txt_saved), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lifecyclescope uses the main thread dispatcher by default.

Comment: Thank you, it is solved my problem:  `lifecycleScope.launch { withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }}`

Comment: Yes, that's the way to properly use it. And you don't need `runOnUiThread` at all. Just keep those parts of code outside the `withContext` block(s).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`lifecycleScope.launch{}` executes the code inside on the `main` thread by default.
Try using the below code to launch the coroutine in the IO dispatcher (for long-running and intensive tasks).

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
       withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.txt_savinginprogress), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
       }
}
```

Comment: This is inside-out. The top-level dispatcher should remain as it is (`Main`) and only the blocking work must go into `withContext(IO)`

Comment: Does exchanging them lead to performance issues or does it go against best practices

Comment: There are some theoretical performance issues, like handing off to an IO thread only to immediately hand off back to the UI thread, but that's not so relevant. It just makes the code uglier and harder to follow when you do it this way. OTOH, it varies by use case, if you have many IO calls and only one UI access in the middle of it, this way may result in better code.